# RestController returns sometimes xml sometimes json

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, jackson

I've heard in a course that if you annotate your POJO with **@XmlRootElement**, when you return the POJO or the List of pojos from your **Restcontroller**, you can choose to get it in JSON format (through Jackson Library) or in XML format (through JAXB).
A way to get the two different responses would have been this:

```
http://localhost:8080/tasks       //default method
http://localhost:8080/tasks.json  //JSON response
http://localhost:8080/tasks.xml   //XML response
```

The weird thing for my Spring Boot project is that I've annotated my Task POJO with @XmlRootElement but these are the results of my HTTP requests:

```
http://localhost:8080/tasks      -> I get JSON list of Tasks
http://localhost:8080/tasks.json -> I get JSON list of Tasks
http://localhost:8080/tasks.xml  -> I get Whitelabel error page

http://localhost:8080/tasks/3      -> I get XML list of Tasks
http://localhost:8080/tasks/3.json -> I get Whitelabel error page
http://localhost:8080/tasks/3.xml  -> I get XML list of Tasks
```

The thing is very strange because of .xml and .json work alternatively.
I've tried to annotate also each Task.java attribute with @XmlElement but nothing changes. I've tried to add explicitly the JAXB dependency in my pom.xml (even if in Spring Boot Starter Web there is already) but nothing changes. I've tried to substitute my @Restcontroller with @Controller + @ResponseBody on the request mappings but nothing changes.

here is my POJO Task.java

```
package com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.XmlVsJsonData.entities;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity @Table(name="tasks")
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement
public class Task {

  @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(name="ID")
  @Getter @Setter
  private Integer id;                         //it can be null because it's autogenerated and I don't insert it for databinding

  @Column(name="TITLE")
  @Getter @Setter
  @NotBlank
  private String title;

  @Column(name="DATE")
  @Getter @Setter
  private Date date;                          //it can be null because I use pre-persist and I don't insert it for data binding

  @Column(name="USER_ID")
  @Getter @Setter
  @NotNull
  private Integer fkUser;

  @PrePersist
  private void setDate(){
     this.date = new Date();
  }
}
```

Here is my Spring RestController:

```
package com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.XmlVsJsonData.controllers;

import 
com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.XmlVsJsonData.daos.TaskDao;
import com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.XmlVsJsonData.daos.UserDao;
import com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.XmlVsJsonData.entities.Task;
import com.quicktutorialz.learnmicroservices.XmlVsJsonData.entities.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.List;

@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
public class RestController {

  @Autowired TaskDao taskDao;
  @Autowired UserDao userDao;

  @RequestMapping("/tasks")
  public List<Task> getAllTasks(){
     return taskDao.findAll();
  }

  @RequestMapping("/tasks/{id}")
  public Task getATask(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer taskId){
     return taskDao.getOne(taskId);
  }

  @RequestMapping("/users")
  public List<User> getAllUsers(){
     return userDao.findAll();
  }

  @RequestMapping("/users/{id}")
  public User getAUser(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer userId){
     return userDao.getOne(userId);
  }
}
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: "What can be wrong?" Anything. Please post relevant parts of your code (and spring config)

Comment: I have also faced the same issue, I want all the response in json, but sometimes I was getting xml, then I added this,produces="application/json" with @requestmapping..that resolved the issue

Comment: If your requests do not send a consistent HTTP `Accept` header with the type they require, the API is merely guessing what you want in return. Try adding `Accept: application/json` to your request headers and see if that helps.